# Slow MySQL query on 2mill record table despite indexes

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization, indexing

Struggling to understand why my query is taking ~8-12s to complete when my table has millions of rows. I can force it to use a specific index, and depending on which one it will range from 7s-20s to execute.

**Here is the query:**

```
SELECT 
    thread, msgProtocol, MAX(newestMsg) AS newestMsg, 
    SUM(total) AS total, SUM(unread) AS unread

FROM

(SELECT 
    msgSender AS thread, msgProtocol, 
    MAX(IF(msgSent = -1, msgSendDate, tblMsgs.dateCreated)) AS newestMsg, 
    COUNT(msgID) AS total, 
    SUM(msgRead = 0 AND (msgRecipient = '5555555555' OR msgRecipient = 'chat@eid:19')) AS unread
FROM tblMsgs
WHERE msgRecipient IN('5555555555', 'chat@eid:19') AND msgStatus != 'D'
GROUP BY msgSender
ORDER BY newestMsg DESC
LIMIT 0, 30) a

UNION ALL

(SELECT 
    msgRecipient AS thread, msgProtocol, 
    MAX(IF(msgSent = -1, msgSendDate, tblMsgs.dateCreated)) AS newestMsg, 
    COUNT(msgID) AS total, 
    SUM(msgRead = 0 AND msgRecipient = 'chat@eid:19') AS unread
FROM tblMsgs
WHERE msgSender IN('5555555555', 'chat@eid:19') AND msgStatus != 'D'
GROUP BY msgRecipient
ORDER BY newestMsg DESC
LIMIT 0, 30)

ORDER BY newestMsg DESC
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

The basic premise of this is a chat/texting application that stores messages where the sender and recipient are in two separate columns. Whether a message is "incoming" or "outgoing" is determined in the application. This query is trying to pull a list of most recently updated "**threads**" or conversations. This data updates in real-time as one would expect for a chat app, so it's crucial it's quick. The first half of the UNION grabs what are effectively the most recently updated incoming threads, and the second half outgoing. They are then joined together and grouped again so I only see the latest 30 threads.

**Here is the structure of the table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tblMsgs` (
  `dateCreated` datetime(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `msgID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `msgStatus` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
  `msgSender` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `msgRecipient` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `msgProtocol` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT 'sms',
  `msgBody` varchar(3000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `msgAttachments` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `msgRead` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `msgSent` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `msgDelivered` int DEFAULT '0',
  `msgSendDate` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`msgID`),
  KEY `recipient` (`msgRecipient`,`msgStatus`),
  KEY `sender` (`msgSender`,`msgStatus`)
) /*!50100 TABLESPACE `innodb_system` */ ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2370188 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

**Here is the EXPLAIN:**

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | derived2 |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 30 | 100.00 |  |
| 2 | DERIVED | tblMsgs |  | index | recipient,sender | sender | 1029 |  | 1802478 | 27.01 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 3 | UNION | tblMsgs |  | index | recipient,sender | recipient | 1029 |  | 1802478 | 50.21 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  | UNION RESULT | union1,3 |  | ALL |  |  |  |  |  |  | Using temporary; Using filesort |

I've also tried indexing msgSendDate/dateCreated alone and together and that doesn't seem to help. I've tried forcing both halves of the UNION to use the index "recipient" and "sender" (respectively) and it doesn't help. I'm not sure why the second half doesn't prefer the "sender" index and runs slower with it?

Even using a really simple statement like this will take ~7s (this chooses the "recipient" index as well, and is even slower @ ~9s with "sender"):

```
SELECT * FROM tblMsgs 
WHERE msgSender = '5555555555' AND msgStatus <> 'D'
GROUP BY msgRecipient
ORDER BY msgID DESC
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

EXPLAIN for this:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | tblMsgs |  | index | recipient,sender | recipient | 1029 |  | 1802454 | 50.21 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |

Comment: could you push your limit up into the two union all queries? otherwise it will have to get them all before it can do its limit

Comment: "I can force it to use a specific index"  You NEED to force an index, because you are doing a LIMIT. and SQL does not force the ordering of records, sot the LIMIT would get just a couple of records, and not the first x based on an ORDER.

Comment: @BryanDellinger It's super quick if I push the limit into the two UNION ALL queries but it doesn't give the same/accurate results at all

Comment: You should also have pushed the ORDER BY into the two UNION ALL queries...

Comment: @Luuk pushing ORDER BY into the two UNION ALL queries makes it jump back up to ~8-12 seconds again.

Comment: I am really under the impression there is some sort of indexing issue here but I've tried a dozen different composite and covering indexes and I can't see any marked improvements

Comment: I would guess the issue is that MySQL's optimizer doesn't deal well with `IN` (e.g. `IN('5555555555', 'chat@eid:19')`. I've seen DB2 would finding out the right optimization, but I doubt MySQL engine will do it. Why don't you spell it out by separating it the predicate into two union-ed queries?

Comment: @AlexKozler: Please [edit] the question, and ADD the change query (with moved LIMIT and ORDER)   I think you need to copy the `LIMIT` and copy the `ORDER BY`, so your end query will also have a LIMIT at the end like it has now. The first subquery should produce a MAX of 30 rows, the second subquery to, and the final limit will make sure the total number of records is 30 again.

Comment: @Luuk original question SQL is updated, though as I mentioned it has made no difference in speed with the LIMIT/ORDER BY in the subqueries vs outside.

I understand the thought process as to why it should help, just odd it doesn't.

Comment: @AlexKozler Could you post A) EXPLAIN for the 'really simple statement' for analysis and    B) current EXPLAIN for your current query with date/time to avoid confusion on what we are considering at this time with your current best attempt?

Comment: @WilsonHauck I've added/replaced both EXPLAINs. The question only has data for my "latest" attempts now. The intended/larger SQL is taking ~10s on average to pull data now, and the "really simple statement is ~6s.

Comment: That query seems to need `GROUP BY thread, msgProtocol`.

Comment: How many different values for `msgStatus`?  (The answer impacts optimization.)  Do you need `'5555555555'`?  Having multiple items in the `IN()` hurts optimization.)

Comment: @RickJames There will never be an instance where thread+msgProtocol overlap. The only two msgProtocols currently are "sms" and "chat", and "chat" threads do not use phone numbers, so they always end up different.

Comment: @RickJames msgStatus has ~5 different possible values, all one character. "A" for active is the default. "D" for deleted is the only one I need filtered out/hidden. The "5555555555" is the most common value, the phone number. Chat, where a msgSender/recipient would look like "chat@eid:19", is used much less frequently but still possible. So I do need both, hence the IN()

Comment: @AlexKozler - My point is that the query  has aggregates (`MAX`, `SUM`). Without a `GROUP BY`, the query will return only one row.  Add some more parens and then a `GROUP BY`; do you get something different?

Comment: @AlexKozler  In your 'really simple statement' should you GROUP BY msgSender?  EXPLAIN shows index len of key is 1029 - caused by CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 rather than 256 for simple varchar.  Does your SELECT of '5555555555' not NEED CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 directive to accomodate matching the SAME sets?  Just asking.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I don't think msgSender or msgRecipient used by those indexes would ever be anywhere close to 256 characters, and certainly no special characters in them. utf8mb4 is the default character set of the DBs/tables to support emoji and other fancy unicode, but really only for the message body.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - I _think_ that the charset is adjusted for literals in this case.  (It should be simple enough for the parser/optimizer to do so.)  OTOH, text coming from the client is controlled by the connection parameters and/or `SET NAMES`.

Comment: @AlexKozler We really need to TALK, when you have time.  My profile has contact info. Thanks

Comment: You  should first solve the error in your query (the **error** is: "Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db_1952467845.tblMsgs.msgProtocol' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by")  see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec7646d80f7140c8b4b8be1440d96f06)

Comment: I understand why dbfiddle is barking at those, but they are inconsequential and I'm not using sql_mode=only_full_group_by. My DB's are all using sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION which appears to be the default for AWS RDS MySQL

Comment: Since 5.7.x the default for MySQL includes "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY": see: [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

Comment: @Luuk AWS RDS MySQL 8.0 default parameters specify only NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION, so this does not apply to my situation

Comment: @AlexKozler: You question has the tag `mysql`, and is asked on stackoverflow, so this applies to your question (an maybe not to your situation)

Answer (score 0):

Based on logic you should not need this union -- the following should give you the same result

```
SELECT 
  msgSender AS thread,
  msgProtocol, 
  MAX(IF(msgSent = -1, msgSendDate, dateCreated)) AS newestMsg, 
  COUNT(msgID) AS total, 
  SUM(CASE msgRead = 0 AND (msgRecipient = '5555555555' OR msgRecipient = 'chat@eid:19') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unread
FROM tblMsgs
WHERE (msgRecipient = '5555555555' OR msgRecipient = 'chat@eid:19') AND msgStatus != 'D'
GROUP BY thread
ORDER BY newestMsg DESC
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

By changing to 1 query from 3 the optimizer should pick the best indexes and give you the best performance.

Also, if msgSendDate is null when no messages are sent you can change the 3rd column to

```
  MAX(COALESCE(msgSendDate, dateCreated)) AS newestMsg,
```

which would be much faster than an `IF`

Comment: Your SQL doesn't give the same results. You've stripped off the half that would grab/sort "outgoing" messages. 

A simplified list of messages would look like (dateCreated | msgSender | msgRecipient | msgBody). 

I could send a message to you and you send a message back, this is two records. Your example is only grouping on msgSender, so it's missing a lot...

Comment: One additional note is that msgSendDate can be a datetime in the future (for scheduled messages) so I can't COALESCE() it unless it's marked as "msgSent" (old legacy VB stuff making -1 = true, 0 = false).

Comment: Where are the outgoing messages in your original SQL?  The 2nd select in the union was a sub set of the first one -- so I'm not skipping anything -- the union statement removes duplicates (which you would have had)

Comment: The first half grouped by sender, the second half grouped by recipient. If I am 555-555-5555, I may have both sent and received messages. The table is bi-directional. When I send, I am the sender. When I receive, I am the recipient. 

In your example you are only grouping on messages where I, "5555555555" am the recipient. You are not also fetching ones where I am the sender.

In my original post I am grouping one set of each, one where I send and one where I receive, then UNION ALL, then grouping/limiting by "thread", which is only an alias I used for grouping.

Comment: Still, the `WHERE` is too complex to make any practical use of any `INDEX`.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Hogan suggested, you can re-write the query, and do this:

```
SELECT 
   IF(msgRecipient IN('5555555555', 'chat@eid:19'),msgSender,msgRecipient) AS thread, 
   msgProtocol, 
   MAX(IF(msgSent = -1, msgSendDate, tblMsgs.dateCreated)) AS newestMsg, 
   COUNT(msgID) AS total, 
   SUM(msgRead = 0 AND (msgRecipient = '5555555555' OR msgRecipient = 'chat@eid:19')) AS unread
FROM tblMsgs
WHERE (msgRecipient IN('5555555555', 'chat@eid:19') OR msgSender IN('5555555555', 'chat@eid:19'))
  AND msgStatus != 'D'
GROUP BY 1, msgProtocol
ORDER BY newestMsg DESC
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=27d1bed77f5a39281c4f54a0ef981e4f)

- As far as I can see, this will use index (checked by removing the comment before `EXPLAIN` in the dbfiddle)
- I cannot tell if it is performant enough, because a reproduceable situation is missing (see `Some updates to (TRY TO) reproduce actual data` in the dbfiddle)